# an error in qt_creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I begin to study qt (I have qt creator, last version), so I read the reference how to begin to work with it and I'm trying to compile project "Animated Tiles" but I receive an error, can somebody please explain why:

```
Running build steps for project animatedtiles...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "D:/QT_prog/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" -w 
mingw32-make: Entering directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
D:/QT_prog/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
mingw32-make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
D:/QT_prog/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
g++ -c -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\include" -I"..\..\..\include\ActiveQt" -I"tmp\moc\release_shared" -I"..\animatedtiles" -I"." -I"..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o tmp\obj\release_shared\main.o ..\animatedtiles\main.cpp 
..\animatedtiles\main.cpp:257:20: error: main.moc: No such file or directory 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `D:/QT_prog/qt/examples/animation/animatedtiles-build-desktop' 
mingw32-make[1]: *** [tmp/obj/release_shared/main.o] Error 1 
mingw32-make: *** [release-all] Error 2 
The process "D:/QT_prog/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe" exited with code %2.
Error while building project animatedtiles (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Сборка'
```

Comment: The outpt you've supplied is not enough to tell what is going wrong. Please update with the full error log.

Comment: @Casey: done, so what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the main.moc file hasn't be generated.

Try this:

1. Clean the Project "Build" -> "Clean All"  or "Clean Project "
2. Build the project again, Ctrl+B

If that doesn't work then:

1. Comment out the `#include "main.moc"` line at the end of main.cpp
2. Perform a build, moc should run and create `main.moc`, but the build will fail.
3. Uncomment `#include "main.moc"`, and build again. Should work

**Edit:**

I'm not very familiar with qt creator, so you might also want to try just remove the `#include "main.moc"` line altogether. QMake might be smart enough and figure out what to do.

Comment: Since there was several possible answers, could OP point out here in the comments what the solution was?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution did not work for me. I had to copy main.moc from release_shared up to the directory containing main.cpp. QT 2010.05, Win7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are experiencing this:
http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1889

> I was able to reproduce this issue with Qt SDK 2010.04.
>
> 1. Install Qt SDK 2010.04 on Windows 7
> 2. Open animatedtiles
> 3. Build
>
> **Removing c:\Qt\2010.04\qt\exmaples\animation\animatedtiles\tmp\moc\release_shared\main.moc manually solved the issue.**